# VS 2008: Font Runs Off, How to Reset to Default?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, visual-studio-2008

In Windows 7, after I change the setting for "Language for non-Unicode programs" to Chinese Simplified, PRC), I found that the font settings for VS 2008 runs off as well ( see the image below):
[alt text http://lh6.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/TCbFX0rwQgI/AAAAAAAAFhE/SygU1W8nyc4/font%20runs%20off.png](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/TCbFX0rwQgI/AAAAAAAAFhE/SygU1W8nyc4/font%20runs%20off.png)

The fonts in VS2008 are no longer the default fonts.

Is there anyway to restore the fonts and text size to the default, without change the setting for "Language for non-Unicode programs"?

Answer (score 1):

You can override any Windows settings in VS in Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and colors.

Comment: that's what I did, but still, the fonts are the original one